# Custom Responses in Apache

Tags: linux, apache

I am newbie for LAMP dev environment. is it possible to change the apache responses with a Linux shell script? Let's assume Browser request www.sam.com/styles/main.css and I want to serve www.sam.com/styles/main_new.css not main.css. I want to do this by using apache or Linux script. is this possible ? (sometimes this may be a silly question :D)

Thanks!

Asoka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can learn something about [url rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html). And it is not possible to change the apache response by a linux shell.

Comment: Thanks dude ! I will check this with url rewriting

Answer (score 0):

You can use mod_rewrite.
Create a file named .htaccess in the site root directory with the follow content:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /styles/main.css /styles/main_new.css
```